# bash over Windows SSH is not working

Tags: windows, ssh, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been using an OpenSSH client on Windows for a long time and an SSH server on Linux. Recently I have decided to use the OpenSSH server on Windows 10. I can install it, run the server and login to it with no problem. The default shell is PowerShell and I can run PowerShell commands as usual. I like to run bash.exe after login to my windows machine and that is the problem. It says Access Denied. I have been trying different things and googling but did not find anything useful.
An old thread was mentioning almost the same issue with cygwin SSH. The solution was to change the setting on service and login with the system account along with checking Allow service to interact with the desktop. That didn't work for me either. Bash.exe is working fine when I login to windows normally (not through SSH)so I cannot figure out what is the cause. It is obviously some sort of permission problem for SSH but where is it and how can I change it?

Comment: "*It says Access Denied*" What is "it", and what precisely did you do to get this error message?

Comment: When I login the default shell is powershell. In the powershell I just ran bash.exe

Answer (score 0):

I loved to run bash.exe on windows ssh server but it doesn't work anymore, so I decided to open ssh server on wsl linux, and when I need to use windows program or powershell, I do /mnt/c/Windows/system32/cmd.exe then you can go out to windows rather linux
before ssh -> windows -> wsl
after ssh -> wsl -> windows
it's different, but same